# WebAPI log only when content type equal to json

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, nlog

Currently, I have a handler that registered globally to capture all kinds of request & response. However the system contains a few endpoints which has pdf or csv as content type.

```
   public class LogRequestAndResponseHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
            HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // log request body
            var requestBody = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            LogUtil.Info("[" + request.GetCorrelationId() + "] Call:" + request.RequestUri,"httpTrace");
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestBody))
            LogUtil.Info(requestBody,"httpTrace");

            // let other handlers process the request
            var result = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

            if (result.Content != null)
            {

                // once response body is ready, log it
                var responseBody = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                //LogUtil.Info(responseBody,"httpTrace");
                LogUtil.Info("[" + request.GetCorrelationId().ToString() + "] Return:" + responseBody,"httpTrace");
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
```

I'm using the code above, whenever a pdf endpoint being called, the whole pdf body will be captured into log in binary format.

I wonder what's the best way to filter only json body or header to record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both Client and Server should use the [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header to indicate the content type of the body.

You can check this for both the request and the response - perhaps something like this:

```
public class LogRequestAndResponseHandler : DelegatingHandler
{

    private bool ShouldLog(IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> headers)
    {
        if (headers.TryGetValue("Content-Type", out IEnumerable<string> values))
        {
            if (values.Any(x => x == "application/json"))
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }


    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // log request body

        if (ShouldLog(request.Headers.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value)))
        {
            var requestBody = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            LogUtil.Info("[" + request.GetCorrelationId() + "] Call:" + request.RequestUri, "httpTrace");
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestBody))
                LogUtil.Info(requestBody, "httpTrace");
        }


        // let other handlers process the request
        var result = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        if (result.Content != null)
        {
            if (ShouldLog(result.Headers.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value)))
            {
                // once response body is ready, log it
                var responseBody = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                //LogUtil.Info(responseBody,"httpTrace");
                LogUtil.Info("[" + request.GetCorrelationId().ToString() + "] Return:" + responseBody, "httpTrace");
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

You might need to refine it a little more, perhaps you want to log `text/plain` or some other types too, but this should get you started.